# print only one element at a time of an array in Yii

Tags: php, arrays, yii

I'm building a game and I want print out only one element at a time of an array of questions. Somebody help me.

I'm brazillian, so I'm sorry about my english.

```
public function searchNaorespondido() {

    $nomeusuario = Yii::app()->user->getId();
    $criterio = new CDbCriteria();
    $criterio->condition = "nome='$nomeusuario'";
    $usuario = Usuario::model()->find($criterio);

    //Localizar o ID do usuario logado:
    $listaBD = Yii::app()->db->createCommand(array(
                'select' => array('idCertoOuErrado', 'perguntas', 'respostacorreta'),
                'from' => 'certoouerrado',
                'where' => 'idCertoOuErrado not in (SELECT idCertoOuErrado FROM respostacertoerrado WHERE idUsuario = :idUsuario)',
                'params' => array(':idUsuario' => $usuario->idUsuario),
            ))->queryAll();

    $certoouerrado = array();

    for ($i = 0; $i < sizeof($listaBD); $i++) {
        $certoouerrado[$i] = new Certoouerrado();
        $certoouerrado[$i]->idCertoOuErrado = $listaBD[$i]['idCertoOuErrado'];
        $certoouerrado[$i]->perguntas = $listaBD[$i]['perguntas'];
        $certoouerrado[$i]->respostacorreta = $listaBD[$i]['respostacorreta'];

        $criterio->select = 'perguntas';
        $criterio->condition = 'idCertoOuErrado=:idCertoOuErrado';
        $criterio->params = array(':idCertoOuErrado' => $certoouerrado[$i]->idCertoOuErrado);
        $perg = Certoouerrado::model()->find($criterio);

        foreach ($perg as $m) {
           echo $m;
        }
        echo "<br />";
        echo CHtml::submitButton('Certo');
        echo CHtml::submitButton('Errado');
        echo "<br /><br />";
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the question / problem ?

Comment: I want print out only a question at time. That way will print out all of them.